# If $S\subset W$ and $W$ is subspace, is it ok to say $\operatorname{span}(S)\subseteq W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

I mean, if $S\subset W$ and $W$ is a subspace, then $S$ is either a basis for $W$ or at least spans some subset of $W$, therefore $\operatorname{span}(S)\subseteq W$.

Is it ok? For finite sets it's okay to me, but I'm talking about infinite sets.

> **Span**:
>
> Suppose a vector space $(V,+,\cdot)$, and
>
> $$S = \{u_1,\cdots,u_n\}$$
>
> (and $S$ is a subset of $V$, not a subspace)
>
> $$[S]=:\cap_{w\subset V, w\supseteq S} W$$
>
> In other words, $[S]$ is, by definition, the intersection of all $W$,
>   such that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and $W$ contains $S$.

Update: in fact, using this assumption, I have:

$$[S_1]\subseteq W$$
$$[S_2]\subseteq W$$

**Can I prove that $$[S_1]+[S_2]\subseteq W$$ too?**
*where $+$ means sum of subspaces

Comment: Do you define $A+B$ to be the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain $A\cup B$?

Comment: @Nishant sorry, $A+B = \{a+b|a\in A, b\in B\}$ ($A$ and $B$ are subspaces)

Comment: It is the same (proof in my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ok, but for a proof, I need your definition of span$(S)$.

Edit:

If $S\subset W$, then the intersection of all subspaces that contain $S$ certainly is contained in $W$, because $W$ is one of such subspaces. Note that we haven't used that $S$ or $\dim W$ are finite.

**Proof of** $[S_1]+[S_2]=[S_1\cup S_2]$. Indeed: if $v\in[S_1\cup S_2]$ then $v$ is in every subspace that contains $S_1\cup S_2$, and $[S_1]+[S_2]$ is certainly one of such subspaces, so $v\in[S_1]+[S_2]$. Conversely, if $v\in[S_1]+[S_2]$ then there are some $w_i\in[S_i]$ (for each $i\in\{1,2\}$) such that $v=w_1+w_2$, which is in $[S_1\cup S_2]$.

Indeed, $w_i$ is in every subspace that contains $S_i$. Take a subspace $U$ that contains $S_1\cup S_2$. Since $U$ contains $S_1$, $w_1\in U$, and since $U$ contains $S_2$, $w_2\in U$. Then, $w_1+w_2\in U$. Therefore, $w_1+w_2$ is in every subspace that contains $S_1\cup S_2$, and thus, $w_1+w_2\in[S_1\cup S_2]$.

Comment: Are there alternate definitions that would make this false?

Comment: No, as far as I know, but the proof is different depending on the definition.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: I can't understand your second part. Why $w_1 + w_2$ is clearly in $[S_1\cup S_2]$? I know $v$ is written as $w_1\in [S_1]$ and $w_2\in [S_2]$ but I don't see why is is contained in the span of the union;

Comment: My idea was to show that all the subspaces $W_i$ contain $[S_1]$ and $[S_2]$. Then, show that all them contain $[S_1]+[S_2]$, and since all them contain, then the $[S_1]+[S_2]$ is in the intersection.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: $w_1$ and $w_2$ are in the union, and every subspace that contains $w_1$ and $w_2$ must contain also $w_1+w_2$; then $w_1+w_2$ is in the intersection of all the subspaces that contain $S_1\cup S_2$.

Comment: @ajotatxe but why they're in the union? I mean, I know $w_i \in [S_i]$ but if $S_i$ is not a basis for $W_i$ then there can be some $w_i$ that is in the $\operatorname{span}(S_i)$ but isn't $S_i$, therefore is not contained in the intersection. If it's possible, could you be more clear in the answer and update it for me? I can even open a bounty later and give it to you.

Comment: I have edited my answer to prove that.

Comment: Is it okay if I say: $$x\in [S_1]+[S_2] \implies x = a_1+a_2, a_1\in [S_1]\subset [S_1\cup S_2], a_2\in [S_2]\subset [S_1\cup S_2] \implies [S_1]+[S_2]\subseteq [S_1\cup S_2]$$?